# Sony WH-1000XM3: Microphone doesn't work in stereo mode after changing of bluetooth adapter

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I've changed the bluetooth adapter from USB to one built into my new motherboard.
With USB adapter I could use both good stereo sound and microphone. The device in sound settings was one.
Now I'm using the built-in adapter and I see two devices: Stereo(only sound) and Hands-Free AG Audio (bad mono sound + microphone). And I can't use stereo sound with micro. How can I fix it?

- USB adapter: Buro BU-BT40B
- Built-in: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 9260 (motherboard MSI B450
  GAMING PRO CARBON MAX WIFI)